# Best way to merge rails application with angular grunt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, gruntjs

What is the Best approach to merge angular project into RoR project ?

Please, take into consider that my main project is Ruby on Rails

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at this: http://angular-rails.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this article to setup angular in rails http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we are use **RESTful API** to connect RoR and AngularJS. Try it!